# Add extension method to IQueryable which paginates list and returns json object when returned from a API Controller method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

Hello I have an extension method as follow

```csharp
public static PaginatedList<T> Paginate(this IQueryable<T> queryable, int page, int PerPage) where T : class {
   var total = queryable.Count();
   var list = queryable.Skip(Page * perPage).Take(perPage).ToList();
   return new PaginatedList<T>(list, total, perPage, page);
}

public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T> where T : class {
   public int PerPage {get;}
   public int Total {get;};
   public int CurrentPage {get;}
   public PaginatedList(IList<T> list, int total, int perPage, int currentPage) {
    PerPage = perPage;
    Total = total;
    CurrentPage = currentPage;
    this.AddRange(list);
   }
}
```

And in my controller I have an API Get Method

```csharp
[HttpGet]
public PaginatedList<Site> Get() {
  return dbContext.Sites.Paginate(0, 15);
}
```

The list API returns the list, however, I want to return the response as

```js
{ 
  perPage: 15, 
  total: 100,
  currentPage: 1,
  items: []
}
```

I have tried implementing JsonConverter and other serialization. But I cannot find a method that tells .NET Core to use the format I want it to use while returning response of the PaginatedList Class.

Comment: You don't have a currentPage property in your PaginatedList class, add it and see the output. Also, what do you use it to retrieve it in front?

Comment: Yes, I have added it. The problem is not with the property. Currently the response send list of object like [{}, {}]. But for my scenario, I want an object where it has PaginatedList property and additional items where items is the list. For that I am guessing there should be an interface provided by .netcore. I am simply unable to figure out what that is. I simply call endpoint [url]/api/sites from javascript to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that you have used `inheritance` with your class, and in fact you have to use `composition`

let me clarify, with your current implementation, you inherit from `List<T>`
so when you add properties to your class, you actually add these properties to your list, however, you just need the list to be a property in your class besides the other properties.
so you can change your class as follows:

```cs
public class PaginatedList<T> where T : class {
   public IList<T> List { get;}
   public int PerPage {get;}
   public int Total {get;};
   public int CurrentPage {get;}
   public PaginatedList(IList<T> list, int total, int perPage, int currentPage) {
    List = list
    PerPage = perPage;
    Total = total;
    CurrentPage = currentPage;
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I have returned the instance of PaginatedList class in my actual code. I missed to put that piece of code in the question. I have just edited it. I am looking for an Interface like method create my custom response.

Comment: Yes, I see. Did you test the returned response with swagger ui or postman? Also try to change the type of Get method to `IActionResult` and return `Ok(dbContext.Sites.Paginate(0, 15))

Comment: I test the response in Swagger UI. And I have tried changing return type to IActionResult and return Ok(dbContext.Sites.Paginate(0,15)). This returns the array list. And of course it would do that right? because I have not coded the part where I could customize the output of [obj].Paginate() method. I am searching a way where I could tell .net core to use my custom response block of code when it tries to create response for dBcontext.Sites.Paginate()

Comment: Yes right, I have realized where the problem is. I have updated my answer. I hope it helps

Comment: Yes, your solution fixed my problem. However, the reason I inherited List class is that I want my PaginatedList also to be iterable. For that either I have to inherit from list or I have to implement IEnumerable. If I don't implement IEnumerable solution works fine. However, after implementing IEnumerable, the resulted response is again the same old list. That is why I was trying to find out if there's a method that I can override or implement that can manipulate the resultant json. 
I am giving your solution thumbs up because that is one way to achieve the result that I want.

Comment: Could you please explain more about your goal and what are cases that you will need to iterate over the PaginatedList.? and add this explanation to your question.

Comment: I also want to be able to use PaginatedList like foreach (object o in paginatedList) {} rather than doing foreach(object o in paginatedList.List) {}.